# Delete full row from a form into a database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I want to delete full row from a form into a database in php when i click on delete button. But there are "Undefined index on line 39" issues come on my page and when i click on delete button it redirect me on different page and didn't delete a row.

how can i delete a row on one click ??
Please help me.

Thanks,

Nabeel

```
<body>
<a href="" >delete</a>
<a href="" >create</a>
<label>Read</label>
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","firstphp");
  if($con)
{
}

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users`");

echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>username</th>
    <th>passward</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>delete</th>
  </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['passward'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['<th><a href="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" >delete</a></th>'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}


echo "</table>";
?>
<label>End Read</label>
<br /><br /><hr />
<label>Delete</label>
<?php


if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
  die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
$id = $_POST["id"];
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = $id";
mysql_select_db('firstphp');
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
if(!$result)
{
  die("Could not delete data: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($con);
}
else
{}
?></body>
```

Comment: What's this for `$row['<th><a href="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" >delete</a></th>']`

Comment: mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`...that shouldn't happen.

Comment: to delete a full row from database.

Comment: mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = $id"); this will delete all from the row

Comment: $row[] is defined here for the database values. So that line should be changed. check answer by @simone Nigro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
echo "<td>" . $row['<th><a href="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" >delete</a></th>'] . "</td>";
```

in

```
echo '<th><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?id='. $row['id'] .'&delete=true" >delete</a></td>';
```

and change

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
//...
$id = $_POST["id"];
```

in

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
//...
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

Comment: It work 50% but when i click on delete button. It delete different row